# Default Region Adapters not registered by Prism

Tags: prism, regionadapter

I am currently upgrading the Prism library of an application, going from version 7.0 to 8.1. We use MEF to extend the application, and the older version of Prism had built-in support for MEF. Going to 8.1 we need do some implementation to adapt Prism to MEF, and that is fine. However, the default region adapters that Prism provides are not being registered with the Prism container extension, unless I do that by myself. Later during the bootstrapping Prism tries to resolve them, but that fails, since they are not registered. How come they are not registered at any time, or have I missed something else?

Comment: MEF's not a container, it's a plugin-framework

Comment: Updated my question to hopefully clarify that my question is regarding Prism, not MEF.

Comment: Which container extension do you use?

Comment: We use System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CompositionContainer

Comment: That doesn't sound like a container _extension_...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what information you are asking for to be able to answer my question about the region adapters registration. I'm wondering about why none of the IContainerRegistry.Register* methods is called for the default region adapters, while IContainerProvider.Resolve is called for the default region adapters. Am I supposed to add the registration of the default region adapters?

Comment: For `Unity` and `DryIoc`, [`PrismApplicationBase`](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/2b9873d9a6595c1f50ca9e6f6605d0bb82b0ea5f/src/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/PrismApplicationBase.cs#L69) does the registration. If you implement your own `Application` class, you can't expect them to magically register themselves, can you? Therefore, it may be enlightening to see the code of your `Application` class (or your `Bootstrapper`, if you prefer the classic approach).

Comment: Since a list of other classes, such as RegionManager, RegionAdapterMappings and more, are magically registered without my touch, I thought it would be natural that also the default adapters where registered. Maybe it's due to their constructors are importing a factory that their registration needs to be made according to the selected approach? I'll carry on from there, thanks for taking your time to elaborate on this!